# How to align parts of a div content?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a small info div and want to align right side of info content, i.e. `065 31 323 323`, `qadenza@gmail.com` and `qadenza323` should be left aligned. I tried with different number of spaces and non-breaking spaces - without success.

```
<div id="divInfo">
<div>Mobile - 065 31 323 323</div>
<div>Gmail - qadenza@gmail.com</div>
<div>Skype - qadenza323</div>
</div>

#divInfo{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:29vw;
    border:thin solid red;
}
#divInfo div{
    padding:2px 5px;
    border-radius:7px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#divInfo div:hover{
    background:#e1e1e1;
}
```

the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLjRK/)

Comment: then Y are you using margin-left.. ?

Comment: Looks like tabular data -- use a table.

Comment: @VIVEkUI, yes, I tried margin-left, doesn't work.

Comment: @j08691, I tried the table, but I can't make a `tr:hover` event

Comment: You can make `tr:hover` http://jsfiddle.net/VLjRK/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a table if the rest of the content needs to aligned to the left too. You can use `tr:hover` to change the background as well. http://jsfiddle.net/VLjRK/5/

---

To align the information to the right side and the names to the left you'll have to add an inline HTML element such as a `span` and `float` it to the right. I have updated your jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/VLjRK/3/

Comment: prtksxna, thanks, but info (on the right side) should be left-aligned.

Comment: Ah!I think I understand. If that is the case, then do as @j08691 says and use a table like so - http://jsfiddle.net/VLjRK/4/

Comment: prtksxna, `hover` background is lost

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code. Here is some changes please check -

Add span tag which you want to align right

```
<div id="divInfo">
<div><span>- Mobile</span> 065 31 323 323</div>
<div><span> - Gmail</span>qadenza@gmail.com</div>
<div><span> - Skype</span>qadenza323</div>
</div>
```

Add one css class make float:right;

```
#divInfo span{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Chinmay Sahu, info (on the right side) should be left-aligned

Comment: Ohh sorry i wrongly read your question wait i will changes my code